# I can´t open php page in div tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have problem to open a php page in a div tag.

I use this code. When i try to open a .html file it works fine...

```
<div id="div1" >   </div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
   url: "tabell.php",
   type: "GET", 
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(data){
   $("#div1").html(data);
   }
 });
 });

 </script>
```

any idea whats wrong

Comment: What happens when you got o tabell.php in your browser?

Comment: If you use developer tools (like firebug) go to a "network" tab, there is a result of your asynchronous query. I think it's error in the php file

Comment: or maybe check the console tab in the developer tool.It opens up by "F12" or "ctrl + shift + i" in most browsers.

Comment: I had some error in my php file. Now it´s working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before the output of your PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

Maybe your php script is not returning content type text/html, which is confusing jQuery, since you specifically say you expect html.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `tabell.php` you have to `echo` whatever you want to be passed to the `data` variable in your ajax call. Example: `echo "<div>Hello</div>"`